# For every $x$ and $y$ in the real number set, such that $x<y$, does there exist $z:x+z=y$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

We know that the set $\mathbb{N}$ follows the rule ${\forall}x,y\,{\in}\,\mathbb{N}:x<y:{\exists}z\,{\in}\,\mathbb{N}:x+z=y$.

Is the above, in the form ${\forall}x,y\,{\in}\,\mathbb{R}:x<y:{\exists}z\,{\in}\,\mathbb{R}:x+z=y$, true for the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$?

How to prove it using the definition of $\mathbb{R}$ as "Dedekind complete totally ordered field"?

Comment: You don't need the hypothesis $x < y$ and you only need the fact that ${\mathbb R}$ is a field.

Answer (score 1):

In a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) $F$ we have $-a$ for every $a \in F$.

Consider now: $x < y$.

From the [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) axiom:

> $∀x ∀y ∀z \ 
> [x < y → (x + z) < (y + z)]$

we get:

> $(x + (-x)) < (y + (-x))$.

But $x + (-x)=0$ and thus: $0 < (y + (-x))$.

Finally:

> $y = y + ((-x) + x) = (y + (-x)) + x$

i.e.

> > $\exists z \ (0 \lt z \land y = z + x)$.

Comment: Why does $y+(-x)=z$?

Comment: @kbvbn - because I've "called" $z$ the number $y + (-x)$.